# Serilog writing to sinks only on non-async actions and, even then, only on first run

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5.2, serilog

I'm attempting to log using Serilog. Right now, I'm hitting two sinks: SQL Server and Elasticsearch (just to make sure it wasn't an issue with one or the other). I'm also testing this in my dev environment, using IIS Express and debugging with Visual Studio 2013. Configuration is very simple:

```
var log = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.Debug()
    .WriteTo.MSSqlServer(logConnectionString, "__Serilog")
    .WriteTo.Elasticsearch(new ElasticsearchSinkOptions(nodes) {
        AutoRegisterTemplate = true
    })
    .CreateLogger();
```

Invariably, async controller actions never log anything and non-async controller actions only log on first load. Each subsequest request to the same action does nothing. I confirmed this by creating a very simple test platform:

```
[Route("test")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Test()
{
    logger.Information("Test Action");
    return View();
}

[Route("testasync")]
public async Task<ActionResult> TestAsync()
{
    logger.Information("Async Test Action");
    return View();
}
```

After hitting both actions numerous times, I had one and only one log entry: "Test Action".

The fact that I'm getting *any* logs (which are making it to both SQL Server and Elasticsearch) suggests that everything is configured properly. However, I'm at a total loss as to why only some are making it and not others. Also, I considered that the timing may just be delayed due to batching, but I've waited hours now, with nothing ever showing up.

Just to confirm there were no exceptions being raised, I added the following:

```
Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable((msg) => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(msg));
```

But nothing is ever logged to the debug output.

Finally, for what it's worth, I'm using Ninject to inject the Serilog instance:

```
kernel.bind<ILogger>().ToConstant(log).InRequestScope();
```

I don't think that really matters here, but who knows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible that Ninject's `InRequestScope` configuration is **disposing** the logger at the end of each request. Serilog loggers (and sinks) flush and shut down upon disposal, which would explain why the events raised synchronously in the controller are making it through.

To verify this, try registering the logger as a singleton.

(You'll need to make sure there's only one `log` instance created, but I assume by `ToConstant(log)` that you're only setting this up once.)

Comment: Awesome. That was it. I changed `InRequestScope()` to `InSingletonScope()`, and it looks like it's working every time now. The weird thing, though, is that what you said makes sense regarding the async actions, but it doesn't explain why the non-async action logged only once. Seems it would have either failed always or worked always. Regardless, this change helped there too.